# How to allow remote MSSQL user to bulk insert my local txt file?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, logins, database-user

I have a txt file on my local PC. I run localy Java app which connects to remote MSSQL. Now I need to bulk insert from that text file into my database table.

However, SQL login can't read my file. I get:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot
> bulk load because the file "D:/My_Files/my_file.txt" could not be opened.
> Operating system error code 21(The device is not ready.)

I set permissions on My_Files folder for 'Everyone'. I can't create a Windows user with the same name like SQL login because it is too long for Windows user. Is there a solution?

Comment: A remote SQL Server has no way of reading a file on your local PC. Try `bcp`.

Comment: Why not have the Java app bulk insert into your database after reading from the file itself?

Comment: I am calling a store procedure from Java. This store procedure uses bulk insert from my local txt file to a table in remote db.

Comment: J.D. that could work too, but I wrote the code like this, to bulk insert from a store procedure and it worked fine localy. Now I deployed my code and have trouble with remote db user accessing my text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mustaccio pointed out, a local **path** is not going to be accessible from the SQL Server, which is the error you're receiving regarding "*D:/My_Files/my_file.txt*. It's looking for a file on the D: drive on the server that your SQL instance is installed on (not your local computer's D: drive).

You *may* be able to create a network share to that folder and reference it by UNC path in the SQL Server instance though. How to do that is more so in the scope of a [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) question.

Alternatively you can add code in your Java program to read the local file and then do a `BULK INSERT` command from the app to your database.